# Adding simple HTML tags directly in edit source?

Tags: 2013, html

Is it **not** recommended to add some simple HTML with style directly on a page using "Edit Source"?

I'm not feeling for creating a custom CSS file for one page only.

Let me hear your thoughts! Pros and cons?

Comment: in content editor? or page content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Edit Source' dialog frequently modifies the source that you enter before saving it to the page. You'll often find that custom classes, styles, spacing, markup, etc. are changed/modified/added/removed by SharePoint as it attempts to avoid possible conflicts.

Simple solution to your scenario (a single page where you want some minimal customization) is to use a text file in an asset library as the source for a content editor web part, then you can specify any HTML (including styles in a `<style>` tag) in the text file and it will be rendered appropriately on the page with the content editor.

Comment: nicely said @John-o

Answer (score 2):

I like John-o's answer, but if the HTML is simple enough that it won't be modified by SP, then go ahead and add it to the page. But my preference would be to add it via a content editor part, simply do to the fact that it makes it easier for other developers to figure out how the page was changed later on. (Meaning, if I am responsible for editing a page that someone else created, I will definitely see that there is a content editor part, but I may not notice that there is hand-crafted HTML directly in the page source.)

Comment: This is a really good point (about not being able to find some HTML source) and I would add another downfall of the source editor for maintainability is that it definitely removes all the whitespace from your markup (to save itself 0.00001 or so ms in load time...) and thus makes anything even very slightly non-trivial impossible to read/change later